# Image won't center in ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a grid containing seven rows of five `ImageView`s. I want to center the images in the views. I've tried setting every layout, gravity, and foregroundGravity property in the xml to centered, but nothing seems to center it. I read a few stackoverflow posts and they all suggested doing things I'd already tried.

The grid is closer to the left side than the right, and when I touch an image, the highlighted area has more space on the right side of the image than the left.

Any suggestions on how to get them to center?

Here's my layout file:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
  >
  </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the class that I'm using it in:

```
class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context context;
  private final List<Button> buttons;

  CustomGrid(Context c, List<Button> buttons) {
    context = c;
    this.buttons = buttons;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() { return buttons.size(); }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) { return null; }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) { return 0; }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
      grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);

      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
      imageView.setImageResource(buttons.get(position).getBasicImageId());
      buttons.get(position).setImageView(imageView);
    }
    else {
      grid = convertView;
    }

    return grid;
  }
}
```

And here's the image. For now I'm just using an Android stock image.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M6,18c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h1v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L11,19h2v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L16,19h1c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1L18,8L6,8v10zM3.5,8C2.67,8 2,8.67 2,9.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S5,17.33 5,16.5v-7C5,8.67 4.33,8 3.5,8zM20.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5v-7c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5zM15.53,2.16l1.3,-1.3c0.2,-0.2 0.2,-0.51 0,-0.71 -0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0l-1.48,1.48C13.85,1.23 12.95,1 12,1c-0.96,0 -1.86,0.23 -2.66,0.63L7.85,0.15c-0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0 -0.2,0.2 -0.2,0.51 0,0.71l1.31,1.31C6.97,3.26 6,5.01 6,7h12c0,-1.99 -0.97,-3.75 -2.47,-4.84zM10,5L9,5L9,4h1v1zM15,5h-1L14,4h1v1z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Have you tried using scaleType="center" in ImageView

Comment: All that does is make the images smaller. They're still offset to the left.

Comment: Please try android:scaleType="centerCrop" to crop Center.

Comment: Instead of hard coding layout_width and layout_height, try using wrap_content or match_parent